# Asymptotic relations for periodic functions

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

can `n^(1 + sin n)` be written as `O(n^k)` where k can be any positive integer greater than or equal to 2(k>=2)?
And are asymptotic notations defined only for increasing functions with constant growth rate or they can be applied to wider range like decreasing function or periodic function? More insights about the same are very much welcomed.

Comment: n^(1 + sin n) = O(n^2). The other parts of your question are varied, but a good place to start would be to look at a book on computational complexity or the wikipedia page in big-O to see what sorts of functions big-O and its ilk are defined on.

Comment: @Paul Hankin I read Introduction to algorithms by Thomas Cormen but didnt find any thing which clears my doubt. I asked my professor but he too got stuck at the point that if we can use asymptotic notation for periodic  function or not. So its still a mystery for me. Thanks for replying:)

Comment: The answer is that you can use them on any functions. For example on wikipedia, the formal definition starts: "Let f and g be two functions defined on some subset of the real numbers." It doesn't restrict f and g further than that.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks:)

Comment: Decreasing (positive) functions are always O(1). They can sometimes be even smaller -- for example O(1/n).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use asymptotic notation for periodic functions, but not for all.
The maximum value of **sin(x)** is **1**, and minimum value is **-1**. 
So we can say there's a subset of the natural numbers such that the restriction of **f: n -> n<sup>(1 + sin n)</sup>** to it is **O(1)**

Comment: Thanks:) what about decreasing functions?

Comment: It's nit-picking maybe, but best case / worst case tends to describe time complexities of algorithms given good / bad inputs of a given size n. Here there's just a function -- no time, and no algorithm. I guess you mean something like "there's a subset of the natural numbers such that the restriction of f: n -> n^(1 + sin n) to it is O(1)" but that's not usually what's meant by "best case complexity".

Answer (score 0):

You can use asymptotic relation for periodic functions.Here in your question 
`n^(1 + sin n) = O(n^2)`.
We can use `f(n)=Θ(g(n))` means we can give both lower bound and upper bound to the function.

```
f(n)=Θ(g(n)) iff
f(n)<=c1.g(n)
f(n)>=c2.g(n)
```

where c1 and c2 are some constants.